# emacs 24.5 Args out of range: #<buffer *scratch*>, 9017, 10107

Tags: emacs

I just finished upgrading to emacs 24.5. After starting up emacs, I got the error message:
"run-hooks: Args out of range: #, 9017, 10107"
This error does not show up when using emacs 24.3,
I suspect it's related to yassnippet but not sure. Does anybody encounter similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was running emacs 24.5 for quite a few months and never encountered that particular error. It is almost certainly being caused either by something in your init file or one of the packages you have installed. Try running with -q and see if you get the error - if you don't, then it is definitely something being done in your innit file.

In general, compiled elisp is backwards compatible, but I have found it good practice to re-compile all *.elc files when you upgrade to a new version. If you haven't done that, highly recommend doing that and see if that fixes the problem.

Use the --debug-init command line option when starting emacs to get a more meaningful backtrace which will help you identify where in your init the problem is being generated. At the vary least, this should provide you with enough info to post a more targeted quesiton, which will usually provide more useful assistance.